# Process class start leak memory

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, process.start

I have a program which launches regularly another process with `Process.Start()` function.

After some hours, I can detect a memory leak with Windows resource monitor.
I can see tons of Handles typed `"Key"` on:

> "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.exe"
>
> "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\exefile"
>
> "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\exefile\shell\open"

here is my code:
my code is really simple :

```
            Process streamerProcess = new Process();
            streamerProcess.StartInfo.FileName = SEStreamRequester.StreamerPath;
            streamerProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;

            try {
                streamerProcess.Start();
                m_streamerPid = streamerProcess.Id;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                m_streamerPid = 0;
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(
                    string.Format("Error while start streamer:{0}", e.Message)
                    , e
                );
            }
            finally {
                streamerProcess.Dispose();
            }
```

where `parameters` and `SEStreamRequester.StreamerPath` are string

I searched in my code if I correctly disposed all Process instance, and I think so. How do you confirm these Handles are used by Process instance ?
How can I find from where the leak comes ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide some code so we have some idea of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to formulate an answer with the context you gave. if you don't dispose the Process object after you are done it will be kept alive.

I suggest you use a Using for the initialization of the Process. After the block had finished the Using will dispose the Process for you.

```
 using (Process process = new Process("Cmd.exe", commandString))
        {
         process.Start();
        }
```

As long as you have really disposed the object('s). the garbage collector should do the rest! maybe check out the following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2

And this one for more information about garbage collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/

Comment: I don't use ```using``` but call ```Dispose()```

Comment: @oliviersow Have you debugged and watched if the garbage collector was triggerd at some point while running your application?

Comment: I don't know how to watch if the garbage collector was triggerd, can you explain to me how to do ?

Comment: If you look at your Diagnostic Tools while running -> https://gyazo.com/c57dfe761cbdd2da303a6b5692256b83
You can see the yellowish pointer that indicates when the GC was triggerd and if it was forced or not

Comment: if i open my Diagnostic Tools window while running, i can select only CPU usage. Memory Usage and UI Analysis are disabled

Comment: can i use `Memory Usage` in VS2017 when coding in c# .net version 2 ?

Comment: Should be available from .Net version 2.0 and >

Comment: unfortunally: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/264575/diagnostic-memory-usage-is-disabled.html

Comment: Too bad indeed, Why are you writing it on .Net 2 .0 if I may ask?

Comment: Because i start when .net2 was preinstalled in Windows. I should change it